# Header not merged in View - Report Builder

Tags: merge, header, reportbuilder

I have added an extra top row for easier overview of my Report Builder report.
Two of these are easy to Merge into one cell.

One give me troubles, as when I runt he report, the header is split into four cells.

Most likely due to the Parent/Child relationship of the below rows I have setup.
Is there an easy way to make this header merged into one cell no matter how many columns that pops up below it?

Thanks,

[Report Builder header issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGBjH.png)

[Report Builder Design overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcV8t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, done. I Simply had to add a header line above and outside the scope of the child/parent columns